# Display menu PHP as per timeslot PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySQL DB which stores Menu served by restaurant on each weekday and in time slots.

Table structure is as below:

```
i_type      i_name    i_cost   i_day   i_start     i_end
--------------------------------------------------------
Breakfast   Prantha   20         0      07:00      11:00
Lunch       Special   80         0      11:01      15:00
Dinner      Special   100        0      15:01      21:00
```

Where 0 = Sunday and so on.

e.g Breakfast (07:00 to 11:00) , Lunch (11:01 to 15:00)

Now the menu as per day of the week is displaying perfectly fine. But i want menu to be displayed as per below approach:

1. If Customer is accessing restaurant in morning time i.e. in time of breakfast or earlier then he shall be allowed to order Breakfast,Lunch and Dinner.
2. If Customer is accessing restaurant in lunch time then only lunch and dinner shall be allowed to be ordered not the breakfast.

To get the day of week i am using below approach

```
$jd=cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"));
$dw = (jddayofweek($jd,0));
```

Currently i am handling timeslot as below:

```
$datr = (int)date('Hi');
$timew= str_replace(':', '', $row['i_start']); $timec= str_replace(':', '', 
$row['i_end']);
if (($datr < $timew) || ($datr > $timec)) { ?>
<button class="btn btn-default" style="background:#ED3E49;border-color: 
#E31522;color:#fff;padding:5px;border-radius:5px" disabled="disabled">
&nbsp;Ordering Closed</button> } ?>
```

But above approach is not letting me to order lunch when i am in breakfast time and so on.

Comment: but why typecasting is required them... comparison i just working fine but question here is to play with condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $dayValueFromDB = $row['i_day'];
    $jd=cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"));
    $currentDayValue = (jddayofweek($jd,0));
    //for just today and tomorrow the last condition in if is for the senario if today in saturday and tomorrow is sunday
    if($dayValueFromDB == $currentDayValue || $dayValueFromDB == ($currentDayValue+1) || ($dayValueFromDB == 0 && $currentDayValue==6))   
    if ($datr > $timec){
        //your code
    }
    }
else{
    //for all other days display no order will be taken or whatever you like
    }
```

Comment: nops.. this approach i have tried and it lets to order breakfast even after 11:00

Comment: yes noob... as today is friday.// so i want menu to be displayed for friday and saturday

Comment: i am displaying as if the day value in the database === Current day successfully. But client wants here that only next day shall be visible not all days